# MySQL Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - Radipanel

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a panel that I am unfamiliar with; my friends and I can't seem to resolve this issue. I've looked for missing commas and values that might not add up however can't seem to see a solution.

I keep getting the error: MySQL Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 so I thought I'd see if any good internet Samaritan would lend a hand.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php

    if( !preg_match( "/index.php/i", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ) { die(); }

    if( $_GET['id'] ) {

        $id = $core->clean( $_GET['id'] );

        $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$id}'" );
        $data  = $db->assoc( $query );

        $data['ugroups'] = explode( ",", $data['usergroups'] );

        $editid = $data['id'];

    }

?>


   <?php
                     $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");
                                $array = $db->assoc($query);

  if ($user->data['id'] == "{$editid}") { 
$db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Attempted to edit own account  <font color=\"FF0000\"><b>Denied</b></font>', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})', '1') " );
die("<div class=\"square bad\">
<strong>Error</strong><br>
You cant not edit your own account! Log Inserted!</div>");  }
                    ?>


<form action="" method="post" id="addUser">


    <div class="box">

        <div class="square title">
            <strong>Edit User</strong>
        </div>

        <?php

            if( $_POST['submit'] ) {

                try {

                    $username = $core->clean( $_POST['username'] );
                    $password = $core->clean( $_POST['password'] );
                    $email    = $core->clean( $_POST['email'] );
                    $habbo    = $core->clean( $_POST['habbo'] );
                    $dgroup   = $core->clean( $_POST['dgroup'] );
                                        $banned   = $core->clean( $_POST['banned'] );
                    $jobtitle = $core->clean( $_POST['jobtitle'] );
                    $forumuser = $core->clean( $_POST['forumuser'] );
                    $skypeuser = $core->clean( $_POST['skypeuser'] );
                    $notes = $core->clean( $_POST['notes'] );


                    $query    = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups" );

                    while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {

                        if( $_POST['ugroup-' . $array['id']] ) {

                            $ugroups .= $array['id'] . ",";

                        }

                    }

                    $password_enc = $core->encrypt( $password );

                    if( !$username or ( !$password and !$editid ) or !$dgroup or !$ugroups ) {

                        throw new Exception( "All fields are required." );

                    }
                    else {

                        if( $editid ) {

                            if( $password ) {

                                $password = ", password = '{$password_enc}'";

                            }
                            else {

                                unset( $password );

                            }

                            $db->query( "UPDATE users SET username = '{$username}', password = '{$password}', email = '{$email}', habbo = '{$habbo}', displaygroup = '{$dgroup}', usergroups = '{$ugroups}', banned = '{$banned}', jobtitle = '{$jobtitle}', forumuser = '{$forumuser}', skypeuser = '{$skypeuser}', notes = '{$notes}', WHERE id = '{$editid}'" );


                        }
                        else {

                            $db->query( "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password_enc}', '{$email}', '{$habbo}', '{$dgroup}', '{$ugroups}', '{$banned}', '{$jobtitle}', '{$forumuser}', '{$skypeuser}', '{$notes}');" );


                                            }

                        echo "<div class=\"square good\">";
                        echo "<strong>Success</strong>";
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "User added!"; 
                        echo "</div>";
$db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Edited user $username <font color=\"51c833\"><b>Success</b></font>', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})', '1') " );


                    }

                }
                catch( Exception $e ) {

                    echo "<div class=\"square bad\">";
                    echo "<strong>Error</strong>";
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    echo "</div>";
$db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Edited user $username <font color=\"FF0000\"><b>Fail</b></font>', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})', '1') " );

                }

            }

        ?>

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <?php

            if ($data['banned'] == "1") {
            ?>
            <div style="background: red; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"><strong>User is currently banned!</strong></div>
            <?php
            }

                // User Management Display Group     
  if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "4") {

$db->query( "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, 'Edit User, Wrong Perms  <font color=\"FF0000\"><b>Denied</b></font>', NULL, '<b>{$user->data['fullUsername']}</b> ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})', '1') " );
die("<div class=\"square bad\">
<strong>Error</strong><br>
You have the Incorrect Display group, Please contact an Administrator for assistance</div>");  }


            // Radio Management Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "39") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }

            // Forum Events Management Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "52") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }

            // Events Management Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "41") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }
            // News Management Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "40") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }
            // Community Manager Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "38") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }
            // Administrator Display Group  
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "31") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE admin = '1'" );

                }
            // Panel Administrator Display Group 
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "32") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE snradmin = '1'" );

                }
            // Developer Display Group 
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "42") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE mgmt = '1'" );

                }

            // Owner Display Group 
  else if ($user->data['displaygroup'] == "5") { 


                    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM usergroups" );

                }




                else {
            // Random code to hide the page from everyone else


die("<div class=\"square bad\">
<strong>Error</strong><br>
Sorry you do not have the correct permission to view this page! Contact an admin!</div>");

                }



                while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {

                    if( in_array( $array['id'], $data['ugroups'] ) ) {

                        $groups[$array['id'] . '_active'] = $array['name'];

                    }
                    else {

                        $groups[$array['id']] = $array['name'];

                    }

                    if( $array['id'] == $data['displaygroup'] ) {

                        $dgroups[$array['id'] . '_active']  = $array['name'];

                    }
                    else {

                        $dgroups[$array['id']]  = $array['name'];

                    }

                }

                $opt_banned = Array (
                            "0" => "Active",
                            "1" => "Banned"
                );


                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "required",
                                        "username",
                                        "Username",
                                        "The new username.",
                                        $data['username'] );

                echo $core->buildField( "password",
                                        "<?php if( !$editid ) { ?>required<?php } ?>",
                                        "password",
                                        "Password",
                                        "" );

                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "",
                                        "email",
                                        "Email",
                                        "The new email (optional).",
                                        $data['email'] );


                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "",
                                        "habbo",
                                        "Habbo name",
                                        "Staff Members Habbo Name",
                                        $data['habbo'] );

                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "",
                                        "jobtitle",
                                        "Job Title",
                                        "The staff members job title",
                                        $data['jobtitle'] );

                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "",
                                        "forumuser",
                                        "forum username",
                                        "The staff members forum Username",
                                        $data['forumuser'] );

                echo $core->buildField( "text",
                                        "",
                                        "skypeuser",
                                        "Skype username",
                                        "The staff members skype useranme",
                                        $data['skypeuser'] );


                echo $core->buildField( "left_textarea",
                                        "",
                                        "Notes",
                                        "Acc Notes",
                                        "The staff members Notes",
                                        $data['notes'] );



                echo $core->buildField( "select",
                                        "",
                                        "banned",
                                        "Banned",
                                        "To ban a user, enter 1, thus restricting them from logging in or 0 to not ban.",
                                        $opt_banned );


                echo $core->buildField( "select",
                                        "required",
                                        "dgroup",
                                        "Display group",
                                        "The user's display group.",
                                        $dgroups );



                echo $core->buildField( "checkbox",
                                        "required",
                                        "ugroup",
                                        "Active usergroups",
                                        "The user's active groups.",
                                        $groups );


            ?>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="box" align="right">

        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </div>

</form>
<?php
    echo $core->buildFormJS('addUser');

?>
```

Comment: When you are posting question. Please paste your code in readable format. It's very difficult to find a typo error.

Comment: Sorry! it's my first use of stackoverflow. Will do in the future

Comment: So you deleted this code all-together and found out the problem is with some other code in your project, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your table structure, but simply: your number of values doesn't match the number of columns in your table 'logs'.

Answer (score 0):

If I looked at it right, your query breaks down to this:

```
$value1 = 'Attempted to edit own account  <font color=\"FF0000\"><b>Denied</b></font>';
$value2 = $user->data['fullUsername'];
$value3 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "INSERT INTO logs VALUES (NULL, '$value1', NULL, '<b>$value2</b> ($value3)', '1')";
```

I don't see where you specify which columns to insert those values into.... How can we determine a mismatch without table structure?

example from my DB:

INSERT INTO `articles`(`id`, `title`, `content`, `createdby`, `lastmodified`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])

Comment: Even without any use of the log table it still returns an error (I removed the code all together). Sorry about not posting a table structure.

Answer (score -1):

I've worked with Radipanel before its a interesting system. I personally can't see the issue with this piece of code, are you getting an error after you submit the form? If so it could be a column name mismatch, radipanel is very specific in the way that it collects table information.